# Problemas con peticion AJAX con JQuery en php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un código en jquery que manda una peticion por medio del método load enviando una url con dos variables por GET en php llamando luego una función para eliminar determinado registro de una tabla en una base de datos. El problema radica en que al parecer me captura mal el dato del id del registro de la tabla, porque cuando doy clic en el icono de eliminar me borra otro registro que no he seleccionado. El código JQuery es el siguiente:

```
 function mostrarFormulario() {
                $("#delete-paciente").dialog("open");
            }

            $(function () {
                $("#delete-paciente").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    height: "auto",
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Eliminar": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            url = "index.php?accion=eliminarPaciente&idPaciente=" + $("#oculto-pac").attr("value");
                            $("#eliminarPaciente").load(url);

                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

El código PHP que tiene el valor del id del registro es el siguiente (id en el campo oculto que se llama oculto-pac):

```
 <td><a href="index.php?accion=verPaciente&idpaciente=<?php echo $fila->idpaciente ?>"><img src="Vista/imagenes/eye.png" height="24" width="29" /></a></td>
 <td><a href="index.php?accion=modificarPaciente&idpaciente=<?php echo $fila->idpaciente ?>"><img src="Vista/imagenes/editar.jpg" height="24" width="29" /></a></td>
 <td><a onclick="mostrarFormulario()"><img src="Vista/imagenes/eliminar.png" height="24" width="29" /></a></td>
   <input type="hidden"  id="oculto-pac" value="<?php echo $fila->idpaciente ?>" />
```

Se supone que debe capturar el valor del campo que es, pero al dar clic borra otro registro. ¿Cual puede ser el problema?. Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Antes de realizar la petición con ajax, si imprimís el 'idpaciente', te muestra el correcto?

Comment: Al parecer si, imprimi los valores al lado del campo oculto y me aparecen los que son. No se porque elimina el registro que no es.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un atributo id para tu hidden y este se repite n veces, deberias usar una clase.

Opcion1: Puedes enviar el id por medio de la funcion

```
mostrarFormulario(<?php echo $fila->idpaciente ?>)
```

Opcion2: Tambien podrias enviar el id agregando un atributo a la imagen que se pulsa.

```
<img dato-id="<?php echo $fila->idpaciente ?>" src="Vista/imagenes/eliminar.png" height="24" width="29" />
```

En javascript tendrias que cacharlo asi:

Para para opcion 1:

```
var idPaciente;
 function mostrarFormulario(id) {
      idPaciente=id;
     $("#delete-paciente").dialog("open");
 }

$(function () {
 $("#delete-paciente").dialog({
...
 url = "index.php?accion=eliminarPaciente&idPaciente=" + Idpaciente;
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me funcionó, ahora si me elimina los registros que debe eliminar. Eres un crack.